# Dealing with a supervisor who does not have subject matter expertise

Tags: communication, teamleader

I am working with a colleague who has asked me for guidance on how they can work with a supervisor who has a low "bandwidth" in understanding technical issues that relate to their job. The point is how can the staff engage productively so that the supervisor does not feel challenged and have a common understanding of the issues and create a good working environment

Comment: This question is way too broad for this site, maybe if you could narrow it to some specific issue you are facing then we could be able to help. I know many non tech supervisors who did great running tech teams.

Comment: Thanks Paul. To clarify supervisor does not have the skill and is not patient enough to listen to advise. In this case do you just let the supervisor "learn" from his stubbornness? However, since I still want to be professional how can I handle such a situation successfully?

Answer (score 1):

> how can the staff engage productively so that the supervisor does not feel challenged

This question is very broad so I can only give a broad answer.

The key is to have a trust relationship with the supervisor. Then the supervisor trusts the tech team to understand and cope with the technical challenges while they concentrate on their role. So this is the angle to work on.

Obviously if technical challenges are not being met, or there are third party issues over the work then this is going to make it harder. Otherwise it's reasonably common to have non technical people in charge of techs.

Comment: This only work as long as the manager has nothing to do. The day I need my manager (coworker is incompetent and needs firing, or technology stack must be upgraded, or new vendor must be picked), they won't be able to take the effective decision. If you reduce the manager to "trust their team" you could just as well rid yourself of said manager

Comment: @Jeffrey there is a lot more to managing than that. A manager is the buffer between the team and third parties, responsible for making sure they stay focused and many other things which have little to do with the tech.

Comment: My manager has a full time job doing things that I would hate to do. So I'd rather keep him.

Comment: I have worked for a manager who was very good at managing, but had limited technical knowledge. Part of my job was briefing him on technical issues that were going to require management decisions.